# Cannot include .h files back one directory

Tags: library

I am working on a project with multiple arduinos. I want my folder structure to be as follows:

```
/
  libs/
    someSharedFile.h
  arduino1/
    arduino1.ino
  arduino2/
    arduino2.ino
```

When I include `someSharedFile.h` in one of my .ino files like this `#include "../libs/someSharedFile.h"`, I get this error `No such file or directory`.

However, when I move `libs/` to `arduino1` and include the shared file like this `#include "libs/someSharedFile.h"` everything works fine.

I am using IDE 1.6.7 on windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino IDE copies the files to a temp folder. You can see that when you compile in verbose mode.
As such the lib folder is not available.
You should place you libraries in [your home folder]/arduino/libraries

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to avoid that for git integration. Is there any workaround where the libraries and the main code could be in the same repo?

Comment: Not that I know of wit the Arduino IDE.

Comment: You could use a symlink that's ignored by git. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I am working in a robotics club at school and I want to make it easy for people to get going without having to install a bunch of libraries first.

Comment: I would advice a better IDE for a robotics club. These can handle these situations and have far better version control integration. Off-course I advice my arduino eclipse plugin. http://eclipse.baeyens.it/